# What was the deal with Sullivan's "veins"?

Tags: special-effects, space-sweepers

In [*Space Sweepers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Sweepers), UTS CEO James Sullivan is shown as developing something like a strongly visible "vein" pattern underneath his skin at several points in the movie - usually, when he becomes strongly emotional, in particular

> when obsessing about the (desired) impossibility of reinvigorating Earth.

What was the reason for that? If it was explained in the movie, I must have missed it; I started wondering whether

> he was maybe an alien or somehow had some nanobots in his system, as well

but even if so, it didn't seem to play a role other than making him visually a bit scarier. Thus, was there any explanation given for that condition of his?

*Remark: I watched the movie in English, so maybe something was lost in translation from the original Korean dialog?*

Comment: Noted on TV Tropes as "Tainted Veins"; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/SpaceSweepers - Likely relating to his longevity treatment

Comment: "*His other powers, if he has any, are never shown in the movie, but it is heavily implied that his long life is not natural. If he does have any powers in addition to long life, they may be related to the grotesque red veins that emerge on his skin when he's angry. On the other hand, those veins may be the result of organ transplants that he has undergone to give him long life. He is shown undergoing a full-body scan that reveals his body is mostly artificial.*" - https://screenrant.com/space-sweepers-netflix-movie-unanswered-questions-mysteries/

Comment: If living to 152 were easy, everyone would do it. Whatever he has done to look 110 years younger, it clearly has some *very* undesirable physical and mental consequences.